# How to integrate product of Bessel and exponential fucntion

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I have obtained the following solution for inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation

\begin{align*}
W(u) = \dfrac{i}{2 \lambda} e^{i \lambda u} \int_{0}^u J_{n}(\lambda u^{'})e^{-i \lambda u^{'}} du^{'}
\end{align*}
Could someone please help me on how to integrate this product of two functions MATHEMATICA? Thank you.

Comment: It has no known closed form: `I/(2 λ) Exp[I λ u] Integrate[BesselJ[n, λ z] Exp[-I λ z], {z, 0, u}]` - neither can _Rubi_  solve it. Maybe you know values for `λ` and `u` and `n` in which case you could numerically integrate, otherwise I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  Yes, $\lambda$ and n are constants.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please add to your question the Mathematica code you have tried and the results you have obtained.

Comment: @Bharath simply saying they're constants doesn't help - you need to provide their values or this cannot be numerically integrated.

Answer (score 2):

Substitution `z->\[Lambda] u,\[Xi]->\[Lambda] u'` helps to reduce the integral to `W[u]=int[\[Lambda] u,n]/\[Lambda]^2`

with

```
int[z_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] :=Block[{\[Xi]},I/ 2  Exp[I z] NIntegrate[BesselJ[n, \[Xi]] Exp[-I\[Xi]], {\[Xi], 0, z}]]
```

which only depends on two parameters .

Answer (score 2):

One gets nice analytical results by specifying the order of the Bessel function. For instance

```
Integrate[Exp[-I x] BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, u}, Assumptions -> u > 0]
```

$$e^{-i u} u \left(J_0(u)+i J_1(u)\right).$$

By following this systematically one obtains the following

$$\int_0^u J_n(x) e^{i x}dx =-n + e^{-i u} \frac{P_{n-2}(u)}{u^{n-3}} J_0(u) + e^{-i u} \frac{Q_{n-1}(u)}{u^{n-2}} J_1(u),$$

where $P_n(u)$ and $Q_n(u)$ are certain $n$-order polynomials of $u$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its great to see some positive answer. Just a question. Any idea on how to chose polynomials $P_{n}(u)$ and $Q_{n}(u)$? @yarchik

Comment: @Bharath You can try to derive the recurrence relation between the polynomials using the recurrence relations for the Bessel functions. Try asking on math.stackexchange